# C++ shell issue with fork program

Tags: c++, bash, shell, fork

I'm working on a program that outputs a lot of text from both a parent and child process. However, when I run the program, it seems to be ending and restarting halfway through as the shell prompt appears in the middle of the output and the program hangs once the output completes (so I press ctrl+c to terminate it). I'm not sure if this is a problem with my code, shell (bash), or the program I'm using (putty). Here's a very simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ostringstream oss;
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        oss << "Parent message " << i << "\n";
    }
}
if (pid == 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        oss << "Child message " << i << "\n";
    }
}
if (pid < 0)
{
    cerr << "Fork failed\n";
}
cout << oss.str();
return 0;
}
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
Parent message 1
Parent message 2
Parent message 3
Parent message 4
Parent message 5
Parent message 6
Parent message 7
Parent message 8
Parent message 9
Parent message 10
Parent message 11
Parent message 12
Parent message 13
Parent message 14
Parent message 15
Child message 1
Child message 2
Child message 3
Child message 4
Child message 5
Child message 6
Child message 7
Child message 8
Child message 9
********@***.edu:~/test$ Child message 10
Child message 11
Child message 12
Child message 13
Child message 14
Child message 15
```

This only happens with programs I use fork() in so it must have something to do with it. Anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the child-process, once forked, is not really connected to the parent process. So when the parent process reaches the end of the program, it will exit and let the child process continue to run in the background.

You can prohibit it by [waiting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for the child process to exit. This will also stop the child process from being orphaned.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I place the wait so that the parent completes first? Or is that not possible? Everything I do causes the child to output all its text first.

Comment: @user1804208 In the parent process of course. :) After the loop in the parent process might be a good place.

Comment: That's what I did, I placed wait(NULL) in that place and the child process is always outputting first.

Comment: Update: Nevermind, I figured out I have to change the placement of the oss output of course!

Comment: Just to add, it is a good practice to exit() in the child process.

Answer (score 1):

What's surprising here? Your parent processes ends and the shell prompt appears. The child process is a little behind (because starting up a process takes non-zero time) so some of its output shows up a little later.

If you don't want this behaviour, why are you `fork`ing in the first place?